# Fork() Child Chain

Tags: c, fork, wait

I have the following code, which creates the defined number of child threads using `fork()`:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define NUM_THREADS     4

int main()
{
        int i;
        pid_t pid;
        for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){ //Do this equal to the number of threads
            pid = fork();//Use this to avoid multiple forking

            if(pid == 0){ //If it's a child process
                    printf("Hello World! Greetings from PID: %ld! :D\n", (long)getpid()); //getpid returns the pid of the process
                    exit(0); //Exit the process
            }else if(pid == -1){
                    printf("Oh no! Could not fork! :( Exiting!\n");
                    return 0;
            }
    }
    int status;
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
            wait(&status);//wait until all the children processes have finished.
    }
    printf("All done! I am the parent process! My PID is: %ld if you were curious! \n", (long)getpid());

    return 0;
```

}

This was provided to us as an example. 
Its output is like:

> Hello World! Greetings from PID: 118358! :D
>   Hello World! Greetings from PID: 118359! :D
>   Hello World! Greetings from PID: 118360! :D
>   Hello World! Greetings from PID: 118362! :D

What I'd like to do, instead of having 1 parent process with many children, is to have the parent create a child process, which creates a child process, and so on for the defined number of threads.  How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to code this yourself? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the term "thread" you used is inappropriate in this situation.
Fork means "creating process" not "threads".

You can use a recursive solution but you have to remember that each process creating a process should wait for the return status in order to avoid Zombie Process. Without using any shared variable between process you can use a single variable counter that gets incremented for each forking. But once the counter variable reached the max value, the "youngest" process, i mean the last process created should exit, and one by one other process will exit.

Here is a simple code that works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_PROCESS 5

int counter = 0;

void child_func() 
{
    pid_t pid;

    if (counter < NUM_PROCESS) {

        counter++;

        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {

            printf("fork failed counter = %d\n", counter);

        }
        else if (pid == 0) {

            printf("Hello world ! Greetings from pid %ld\n", (long)getpid());

            if (counter == NUM_PROCESS) {
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                child_func();
            }
        }
        else {

            long var  = pid;

            wait(&pid);

            printf("My pid is %ld and i am the parent of %ld child, i exit\n", (long)getpid(), var);

            exit(0);
        }   
    }
}

int main(void) 
{

    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {

        printf("Fork failed %d\n", counter);

        return -1;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {

        child_func();
    }
    else {

        wait(&pid);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[See output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKndK.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Your example code uses the return value of `fork()` to distinguish between parent and child.  It continues to iterate in the parent (supposing that `fork()` does not report an error), and it `exit()`s without iterating (after emitting some output) in the child.  This is perfectly routine.

What you propose to do is not very much different; what you describe mainly just swaps the roles of parent and child.  Indeed, you have a simpler job, because each parent only needs to `wait()` for one child.  It can do that either inside the loop or outside, provided only that if the last child `wait()`s then it should expect the call indicate an error on account of that child not having any children of its own.  If the parent does not `exit()` or `return` from inside the loop, however, then it does need to break out instead of iterating further.

Answer (score 2):

This task is the same as converting an iterative solution to a recursive solution. The first step is to remove the `for` loop. And then modify the child code so that each child:

1. prints its message
2. updates a count variable, and if the count is less than the max
3. forks a new child
4. waits for its child

The key is that each child gets a copy of its parent's variables, so if a child updates a count variable, and then forks, the new child will see the updated count.

Comment: Certainly one could implement the desired behavior recursively, but any recursive algorithm can transformed into an iterative one (without change in observable behavior), and *vice versa*.  Therefore, whether the solution is iterative or recursive seems a red herring.

Comment: Well, in a more realistic program, if children are created as a chain, calling functions is probably more natural than looping, because each process will have a meaningful and different purpose.